# one size fits all screen resolution

Tags: android, size, resolution

I am extremely new to Android. Like less than a week new.  I want to size everything to were if it takes up lets say a forth of the screen on one phone I want it to take up 1/4th the screen on all phones. I have been playing around with making my own method for this but I do no like it and there must be a better way. This is what I came up with.

```
public int displayWidth(double ratioIn){
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    double resolutionWidth = dm.widthPixels; //gets the width in pixels
    double ratio = (resolutionWidth/100); //devides by 100 so that ratio will be in terms of %
    int displayWidth = (int)(ratio*ratioIn); 
    return displayWidth;
}
```

Problem is there is a loss of accuracy (although I have tried it with 480 resolution and it is almost perfect).Is there a better method for this? I have tried using dp. It gets close sometimes, but not close enough.

Comment: you could add some more useful tags to your question. like android. **edit:** I'm no android expert, but isn't there something similar to javas layout managers? or dont you use some xml to define you GUI?

Comment: My bad I thought I was asking in the android section. I use xml to define the GUI. I'm new to android, but the difference in this and reg java programming is there are only so many display modes on a computer. Phones seem to have alot more.

Answer (score 1):

If it's ok for you to do that in XML you could use LinearLayouts with the attribute [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_weight). If you want your item to be 3/4 of the screen, just give it a weight of 3 and add an empty view with a weight of 1. But be aware - that's performance intensive.

Comment: I should have also mentioned I am new to XML. I do not know about weight and gravity. I have been playing with it but its only taking up what looks to be half of my width not the height. And lets say I want it to draw a button at half the screen width this method will not do that. This is what I have. Is this right?

Comment: ` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="Work Damnit" />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout> `

Comment: That should look somehow like this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="TEST" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>